# How to force a matrix to be unitary given constraints on some of the elements?

Tags: mathematics, matrix-representation, unitarity

I am working with a matrix of the following form:

$$
A =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} &  Q  & \ldots & Q\\
a_{21} &  Q & \ldots  & Q\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1}  &   Q       &\ldots & Q
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where the $a_{ij}$ elements are real and predetermined, the $Q$'s are placeholders and not necessarily equal to one another, and $A$ is square of size $n$x$n$. I am looking to find values for all $Q$'s such that $A$ is unitary. To do this I have attempted to set up a system of nonlinear equations of the form $AA^\dagger=I$ which yields a system of $n^2-n$ unknown $Q$'s, but only $n^2/2 +n/2$ equations after removing any duplicate equations. Therefore, for $n=2$ the system is over-determined and for $n>3$ the system is under-determined.

My question is, is there a method in which I can solve for $Q$'s to force $A$ to be unitary given these constraints for any size n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just performing the [Gram-Schmidt Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)?

Pick the other $n-1$ arbitrary linear independent vectors and perform Gram_schmidt process.

**Caveat:** This requires that the vector of the first column is already normalized. Otherwise we will have $AA^* = cI $ instead.

---

**Update:** I found another related/exact same question. Here is the link:

[How can I fill a unitary knowing only its first column?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/how-can-i-fill-a-unitary-knowing-only-its-first-column)

Comment: The issue that I found with this method is that once I apply the Gram-Schmidt process my column of $a_{11} ... a_{n1}$ is no longer the same. How do I apply this procedure while keeping the first column constant?

Comment: Ah.. so you mean the vector $u_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{21} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n1} \end{pmatrix}$  has a normalization factor in front of it now, right?

Comment: It is anyway a necessary condition that your first column is normalised. Otherwise $A$ can never be unitary. Picking random linearly independent vectors for the rest and performing Gram-Schmidt seems the optimal strategy to achieve your goal. Alternatively, you can directly pick random vectors from the orthocomplement of the preceding columns. This will *not* change the first column.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt method is exactly what I need when the first column is already normalized which is the case for me.